# urlib & requests fail "sometimes" to get the final URL

Tags: python, twitter, python-2.7, python-requests

To give an overview of the problem, I have a list of Twitter users "screen_names" and I want to verify wether they are suspended users or not. I don't want to use the twitter search API to avoid the rate limits problem (the list is quite big). Therefore, I am trying to use a cluster of computers to label my dataset (wether an account in my database is suspended or not).

If an account is suspended by Twitter and you try to access them through the link `http://www.twitter/screen_name` you get redirected to `https://twitter.com/account/suspended`

I tried to capture this behaviour using python 2.7 with `urlib` using the `geturl()` method. It works but is not reliable (I don't get the same results on the same link). I tested it on the same account and yet sometimes it returns the `https://twitter.com/account/suspended` and some other times it returns `http://www.twitter/screen_name`

The same problem occurs with requests.

My code:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
screen_name = 'IaMaGuyGetIt'
account_url = "https://twitter.com/"+screen_name
url = requests.get(account_url)
print url.url
req = urllib.urlopen(url.url).read()
page = html.fromstring(req)
for heading in page.xpath("//h1"):
    if heading.text == 'Account suspended':
        print True
```

Comment: If it sometimes works and at other times it doesn't with *both `urllib` and `requests`* then you can be pretty certain that it is the server, not your code, that is at fault here.

Comment: You can see if the request was redirected by inspecting `url.history`, and you can check if `url.url` is still the same.

Comment: The Twitter server only redirects to *once*; it is probably keyed to your IP address. After that redirect, Twitter counts on your browser having cached the redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The twitter server only serves you the 302 redirect once; after that it'll assume your browser has cached the redirect.

The *body* of the page does contain a pointer though, so even if you were not redirected you can see that there is still the link there:

```
r = requests.get(account_url)
>>> r.url
u'https://twitter.com/IaMaGuyGetIt'
>>> r.text
u'<html><body>You are being <a href="https://twitter.com/account/suspended">redirected</a>.</body></html>'
```

Look for that exact text.